# ShellScriptAction equivalent in CDKV2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a project in CDKv1 which i am upgrading to CDKv2. I have a Gitleaks stage in my AWS CodePipeline using CDKv1. Now i want to move this functionality to CDKv2 but the `ShellScriptAction` is deprecated. I tried out with `ShellStep` but ShellStep does not have the project property - [LINK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.ShellScriptAction.html#projectspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-deprecated-titlethis-api-element-is-deprecated-its-use-is-not-recommended%EF%B8%8Fspan).

```js
export class GitleaksReviewAction extends Construct {
  public readonly action: ShellScriptAction;
  public readonly gitleaksImage: DockerImageAsset;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: GitleaksReviewActionProps) {
    super(scope, id);
    this.gitleaksImage = new DockerImageAsset(this, "gitleaksDockerAsset", {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, "../assets/gitleaks"),
    });
    this.action = new ShellScriptAction({
      actionName: "Gitleaks",
      additionalArtifacts: [props.sourceArtifact],
      commands: [
        "find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \\;",
        "find . -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \\;",
        `aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login -u AWS --password-stdin ${this.gitleaksImage.imageUri}`,
        `docker run -v $(pwd):/repo ${this.gitleaksImage.imageUri} --path=/repo --repo-config-path=config/gitleaks/gitleaks.toml --verbose`,
      ],
      environment: {
        buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0,
        privileged: true,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Used to call the class with this -

```js
gitleaksReviewAction.gitleaksImage.repository.grantPull(
      gitleaksReviewAction.action.project
    );
```

Is there an equivalent in the CDKv2 which returns the project property?

Pipeline code -

```js
export class Pipeline extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    ...

    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "Pipeline", {
      pipelineName: "pipeline",
      synth: new CodeBuildStep("SynthStep", {
        input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, "mainline"),
        buildEnvironment: {
          computeType: CodeBuild.ComputeType.MEDIUM,
          buildImage: CodeBuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0,
        },
        partialBuildSpec: buildSpec,
        commands: [],
        role: codeBuildSynthRole,
        primaryOutputDirectory: "cdk/cdk.out",
      }),
      crossAccountKeys: true,
      selfMutation: true,
      dockerEnabledForSelfMutation: true,
    });

    const review = new ReviewPipelineStage(this, "Review", {
      sourceFileSet: pipeline.cloudAssemblyFileSet,
    });

    const reviewStage = pipeline.addStage(review);

    const gitleaksReviewAction = new GitleaksReviewAction(
      this,
      "GitleaksReviewAction",
      {
        sourceFileSet: pipeline.cloudAssemblyFileSet,
      }
    );

    reviewStage.addPost(gitleaksReviewAction.action);
    gitleaksReviewAction.gitleaksImage.repository.grantPull(
      gitleaksReviewAction.action.project
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're switching to the new API for CDK pipelines, which requires more than just using different classes for the steps.

If that's true, the equivalent in the new API is to use `CodeBuildStep`:

```js
gitleaksReviewAction.gitleaksImage.repository.grantPull(
    gitleaksReviewAction.action.grantPrincipal
);
```

This is assuming that `gitleaksReviewAction.action` is of type `CodeBuildStep`.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodeBuildStep.html#grantprincipal

Comment: cool. Thanks. I was so fixated on ShellStep that i oversaw this

Comment: Using the new API for CDK pipelines i am trying to add this construct to the pipeline as a Stage. Somehow the IDE does not show errors but when i do a `cdk synth` i get an error - `DockerImageAsset at 'GitleaksReviewAction/gitleaksDockerAsset' should be created in the scope of a Stack, but no Stack found` Any ideas ?

Comment: Yeah, do you have a stack?

Comment: Yes i have a pipeline stack where i want to add this stage -

Comment: updated code in the question

Comment: I still don't see a stack declaration in the code you posted.

Comment: added the class declaration that extends Stack

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing CDK v1 and v2 packages? I'd post a new question, as this is getting off-topic.

Comment: I have removed all the cdkv1 packages but yeah this is getting off topic. Posted a new one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71734583/adding-a-stage-to-codepipeline-throws-errors